# Process Builder namespace error in Managed Package Patch

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, patch

I am currently having a block around a problem with the process builder in a managed package, specifically when trying to upload a patch.

Basically, the process builder seems to append the package namespace in front of Standard fields (like the Name field).

For example, here is how a formula that is used to build a string to put in a custom field look in the process builder :

```
[namespace__Obj__c].namespace__Lookup1__c.Name  + ' ' + 
[namespace__Obj__c].namespace__Lookup2__c.Name
```

And here is how it turns out when I try to upload a new patch for the package :

```
[namespace__Obj__c].namespace__Lookup1__c.namespace__Name  + ' ' + 
[namespace__Obj__c].namespace__Lookup2__c.namespace__Name
```

Which then throw me a 'Flow Definition' error for the process about the field not existing (obviously) :

> The formula expression is invalid: Field myVariable_current.namespace__Lookup1__c.namespace__Name does not exist. Check spelling.

Anyone encountered this? It's the first time I am getting this error despite having multiple versions and I am a bit puzzled as there's little I can do currently in term of modification in the patch organisation.

Comment: Enjoy your process builder.